# Making excutable jar file using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My project runs fine from Eclipse.

But when I tried to make it into a jar file or executable file it doesn't work.

I used the option "Export-Runnable JAR file"

The following message appears just after the eclipse finished the exporting process

> JAR export finished with wornings , see details.

the details were ..

> Exported with compile warnings:Mario/src/Map.java

and the same for other classes like

> Exported with compile warnings:Mario/src/Player.java

and so on.

So that I used the other option "Export - JAR file"

It works fine and nothing appears while exporting it from Eclipse.

But when I try to open the file it gives me

```
Couldn't find the main class:Frame.Program will exit
```

Somebody have any idea about what the problem is?

Comment: Clean your workspace. Refresh your project. Rebuild your project. Now export as _Executable JAR_.Select proper `Launch configuration` that is which you use to run your program in eclipse and select finish. May be this works.

Comment: What happens when you try to open the `.jar` exported using "Export-Runnable JAR file"

Comment: @Harry i don't know how to select the "proper launch configuration" :S

Comment: @Ahmed: Go to `Run->Run Configurations...`. Check if you have proper config if not then create one.

Comment: still .. maybe there is an issue with loadig the images??

Comment: lol now the problem is "Resource is out of sync with file system"

Answer (score 4):

Your `MANIFEST.MF` file inside the `META-INF` dir should have a `Main-Class` attribute pointing to your main class.

Comment: well,there was an option called "generate the manifest file" . i used it

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Frame

that's what i found in the auto-generated file

Comment: Have you tried placing your `Frame` Class inside some package?

Answer (score 4):

The important thing for executable jar is [Manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html). Make sure it exists and points to the correct class with main method